# Add td to specific column in table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm still new to php and im trying to make a scheduler script with php and trying to add a  tag to a specific column

My code:

```
<table>
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
<th>Column 3</th>
<tr>
<td>3</td> /* I'm trying to get this td in column 3 */ 
<td>1</td> /* I'm trying to get this td in column 1 */
<td>2</td> /* I'm trying to get this td in column 2 */
</tr>
</table
```

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

To make things clear i simplified my code.

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I want to add a row from the database to a specific column sorted by the day of the week, if its date is 25-11-2014 i want to print it in column 2(Tuesday) but now its all printed at monday

Comment: use case option with '' it may work . and we didnt get you properly

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your Question clearly that you want to generate dynamic code to add td by php if yes, below code may useful for you

```
<?php foreach($td_array as $key=>$val){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$key."</td><td>".$val."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```